# remove substring occurrence and anything comes after it

Tags: pandas

dataframe with 'text' column that contains tweets
each tweets has short url in the end i want to remove that url using regex from all rows

string : 'This is Tilly. She's just checking pup on you. Hopes you're doing ok. If not, she's available for pats, snugs, boops, the whole bit. 13/10 https//(short url here i cannot post)'

i need regular expression that deletes 'http' and all that comes after it using regex

```
archive_clean['text'] = archive_clean['text'].replace('https.', '', regex=True)
```

output:

This is Tilly. She's just checking pup on you. Hopes you're doing ok. If not, she's available for pats, snugs, boops, the whole bit. 13/10 //(the rest of the url)

Comment: You have a `.` in your to-replace string, is that intended? Is the output the desired output, or what you are currently getting? If the later, what would be your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as adding a star to the end of that period wildcard you already have. The star matches zero or more repetitions of the preceding item. ([Link to python re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#:%7E:text=Causes%20the%20resulting%20RE%20to%20match%200%20or%20more%20repetitions%20of%20the%20preceding%20RE%2C%20as%20many%20repetitions%20as%20are%20possible.%20ab*%20will%20match%20%E2%80%98a%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98ab%E2%80%99%2C%20or%20%E2%80%98a%E2%80%99%20followed%20by%20any%20number%20of%20%E2%80%98b%E2%80%99s.))

Change the code to be

```
archive_clean['cleaned_text'] = archive_clean['text'].replace('http.*', '', regex=True)
```

to get rid of everything after the `"http"` substring.

That being said, with regex there are pretty much always exceptions.

- Do you want to strip the white-space before the `"http"`? The solution I just provided leaves your example string as `"...boops, the whole bit. 13/10 "`
- Are you going to have some links with no leading `"http"` at all?
- Will there ever be another link in the middle of the text that should not be removed? Example:

  ```
  "This is Tilly. She's just checking pup on you. Hopes you're doing ok. If not, she's available for pats, snugs, boops, the whole bit. Check her out at https://tillythepup.com. 13/10 https://twitter.com/post/xxxx"
  ```

  In this case we should change the regex to be `"http\S*\Z"` which makes sure it only removes the URL that is anchored at the end of the string.

  *(Note: URL must be continuous with no whitespace right up to the end of the string. Anything short of this will not remove the URL as expected. Maybe account for this by pre-stripping the column of whitespaces using `.str.strip()`)*

  Thanks to mozway in the comments for this suggestion.

There are many ways to handle those edge cases, and maybe you have already thought of them, but the simple case that you outlined in your question is fairly straightforward.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `r'http\S*$'` might be better suited if you only want to remove the link that is anchored to the end of string.

Comment: @mozway Good point on that edge case. My provided method will match the first instance of a link that begins with `"http"`. I will update my answer to account for this.